# PHP file_get_contents to get jquery min code

Tags: php, jquery, file-get-contents

I am writing a script that will go through all my .js files and minify them into one .php file to be included on the site. I just run this script after I have edited some js and want to upload it to the live site.

The issue: I can not load the content of jquery-2.1.4.min.js using file_get_contents. I have tried changing the name of the file to jquery.js and that did not help. I do not have any complex javascript in the other files (just random strings) but they open fine.

With the code:

```
if (!file_get_contents($filename)) {
    die ("dammit");
}
```

I get the response of "dammit". All other files are fine though, so I know the file name and path are correct. One of the weird things is that there are no errors coming up (I have used error_reporting (-1); to make sure they will).

Is anyone else able to get the file contents of jquery? Any ideas what would cause this and if it will be a problem with other javascript or css?

As requested, here is the full code:

```
$buffer = $jsStartBuffer;
//get a list of files in the folder (only .js files)
$fileArray = array();
if (is_dir($jsMakeFile["SourcePath"])){
    if ($dh = opendir($jsMakeFile["SourcePath"])){
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){
            $file_parts = pathinfo($jsMakeFile["SourcePath"].$file);
            if ($file_parts['extension'] == "js") {
                $fileArray[] = $file;
            }
        }
    }
}
print_r($fileArray);
foreach ($fileArray as $nextRawFile) {
    $buffer .= file_get_contents($jsMakeFile["SourcePath"].$nextRawFile);
    if (!file_get_contents($jsMakeFile["SourcePath"].$nextRawFile)) {
        die ("dammit");
    }
    echo $jsMakeFile["SourcePath"].$nextRawFile;
}
$buffer .= $jsEndBuffer;
echo $buffer;
$buffer = \JShrink\Minifier::minify($buffer);
file_put_contents($jsMakeFile["finalFile"]["path"].$jsMakeFile["finalFile"]["name"], $buffer);
```

When I put other .js files in there it is fine (I even tried lightbox.min.js and it worked fine!) I have tried a few different versions of jquery.min and they all seem to fail.

Comment: You should probably include the `$filename` you used.

Comment: We need to see the directory structure and the contents of `$filename`. You may be wrong about it, without knowing, so taking your word for it may be a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: I have added the full code above, is this what you need? The fact that any other files work when I put them in that folder shows that the file paths should be fine (as they are created dynamically).

Comment: Have you tried echoing `$jsMakeFile["SourcePath"].$nextRawFile` and seeing what it contains? If I was a betting man I would guess it lacks a directory separator between the folder and file. When you run into problems like this you need to look at exactly what your variables contain -- every single one of them.

Comment: Sverri, I did do that and it was not that problem (both the variables showed what they should have, and if that were the case it would break for every file, not just the one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, solution found. It is to do with the actual file created by jquery.

The way I solved it was:
- Go to the query site, and instead of downloading the required file, open it in a new tab/window
- Copy all the content in this window
- Create a new file where required and name as required
- Paste the content into this file and save it

This new file will now be able to be read by file_get_contents. I would imagine this solution would help if you are trying to work with jquery (and other) files in php in any way and having issues.

Comment: PHP does not care where the file came from, or what it contains... files are just files. It is more likely that it is caused by something else.

Comment: Not sure what else could cause it. The fact that any other file worked fine is weird. If you would like, try it yourself. Download jquery, put the content to a variable with file_get_contents and then try display the variable. Always came up blank for me (and the if statement showed it was not working). Try another file with the same file name and swap them out. It HAS to be something to do with the file, just not sure what!

Comment: I say again, PHP *does not care* what the contents of a file are. It just reads the file byte-by-byte. If you are having problems then it is either that the file does not exist, that it is not readable, that it is corrupt, etc. It has **nothing** to do with the fact that it is jQuery.

Comment: Lol, if you don't want to believe me, try it!